# Using Cordova 3.5.0 to build a pre-android 4.4 app

Tags: cordova

Am using Cordova 3.5.0 to build an android 4.4 app and now i want to test my app in an Android 4.2 phone

I changed target in "local.properties" and "AndroidManifest.xml" to Android-17 but `cordova build --release` still generate an android 4.4 app

Am i supposed to downgrade to Cordova 3.1.0 or less ? or there is a workaround for my problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cordova 3.5.0 and lower support [Android 2.3.x (Gingerbread, starting with Android API level 10) and 4.x](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide). Maybe you missed something in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, make sure it looks like the following:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot. the thing is that while having this config running build command shows `[gettarget] Project Target: Android 4.2.2` and then `[gettarget] Project Target: Android 4.4.2` in the same build and that confused me because i saw only the second one